# set default date air-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, datepicker

I am using [air-datepicker inline](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/).

I need to set the start date for it.

Here is the script and how I am trying to do it.

```
export function load_datepickers_inline():void {
const search_legs_0_datepicker = $("#search_legs_0_datepicker");
const leg_0_datepicker = $("#search_legs_0_datepicker").datepicker({
  language: gon.locale,
  classes: 'inline-picker',
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear:true,
  altField: '#search_legs_0_date',
  selectDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr("data-defaultDate")),
  minDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr('data-mindate')),
  maxDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr('data-maxdate')),
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: (dateText, inst) => {
    const date = new Date(dateText);
    if (!leg_0_datepicker) { return false; }
    leg_1_datepicker.datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
    if ($("#search_legs_0_hotel_date").length > 0) {
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('minDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').datepicker("setDate", date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('minDate', date);
    }
  }
})

const search_legs_1_datepicker = $("#search_legs_1_datepicker");
var leg_1_datepicker = $("#search_legs_1_datepicker").datepicker({
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  language: gon.locale,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear:true,
  classes: 'inline-picker',
  altField: '#search_legs_1_date',
  selectDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr("data-defaultDate")),
  minDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr('data-mindate')),
  maxDate: new Date(search_legs_1_datepicker.attr('data-maxdate')),
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: (formattedDate, date, inst) => {
    if ($("#search_legs_1_hotel_date").length > 0) {
      $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('maxDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('maxDate', date);
      $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').datepicker("setDate", date);
    }
  }
})
```

All is okay, but default date is not hidhlighted. Do I need to set it?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation, selectDate is a function, so you must use it in this way:

```
leg_1_datepicker.selectDate(new Date(2018, 3, 11));
```

Comment: I cannot use selectDate in options?

Comment: In the documentation there isn't an option called selectDate.

Comment: comments from the future :D grabbed from Air Datepicker docs (http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#sub-section-51)
`selectDate(date) dateDate|Array- JavaScript Date() , or array of dates.`
usage: http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#example-custom-content