# How to set initial date selection on air-datepicker.js?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to get dates from PHP and automatically select them on air-datepickers. (With this library :http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/)

Actually, I am initializing a var and then use document.ready to apply this value.

```
var dd_php = new Date('<?php echo $_GET['dd']; ?>'); // dd=2019-01-01

$(document).ready(function() {
    $dd_picker = $('#dd_datepicker');

    $dd_picker.datepicker({
        language: 'fr',
        startDate: dd_php
    });
});
```

Actually, this code doesn't select the tile on the datepicker. I don't understand why. Any idea ?

Comment: Its the format ok, YYYY-MM-D  or DD-MM-YYYY. Do you get an error in your console?

Comment: Format is ok, YYYY-MM-DD. No error on the console. Display example (console.log()) : Tue Jan 01 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) for 2019-01-01. I wonder if "startDate" isn't for the initial visual display. But then I didn't find anything on the docs to set the initial selected date.

Comment: Found this how to set the date .selectDate(new Date(2018, 3, 11));

Comment: selectDate: new Date(2019, 1, 12) (whatever values I set) Doesn't seems to works too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer based on this thread : [set default date air-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769346/set-default-date-air-datepicker)

"As you can read in the documentation, selectDate is a function, so you must use it in this way" (see below)

```
leg_1_datepicker.selectDate(new Date(2018, 3, 11));
```

But also note this, quoted from the documentation : "Plugin instance is accessible through data attribute."

So the final, correct, tested & working answer is :

```
$('#id_datepicker').datepicker().data('datepicker').selectDate(new Date(2019, 2, 7));
```

Comment: http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#sub-section-51
usage: http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#example-custom-content

Answer (score -1):

this work
$('#dd_datepicker').val("your value");